# Refer to sheet by a portion of the sheet name

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet in Excel that I am trying to call in VBA. This is the way I call it:

```
mainMetrics.Sheets(Sheet10).Range("A1:A1").Select
```

The sheet has the name "Data Dump August" but I don't want to call it like that because that name could change but the sheet number never will. For some reason VBA won't let me call it like this.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can call it like: `Sheet10.Range("A1:A1").Select`

Keep in mind that a sheet in VBA has a "Name" (which is the name on the tab of the sheet) and a "CodeName" which is visible in the VBAProject tree in your VBA/Macro editor. This style of reference uses the "CodeName"

To see that go to View>>Project Explorer.  The open up your workbook in the tree and see the sheet names. The will look like Sheet1(Sheet1) or Sheet10("My Tab Name")

Comment: I added an update to my answer that may help you out. VBA sheet names can get confusing because Sheet.Name and Sheet.CodeName are two different things. CodeName is static and but Name can change to whatever you name the tab.

Comment: Furthermore... is `mainMetrics` a workbook object that you declared and set already, or is that just the workbook name?

Comment: Oh I see. But what I don't understand is my codeName is Sheet10. So shouldn't `mainMetrics.Sheet10.Range("A1:A1").Select` work?

Comment: I just tried this... it looks like referencing this way isn't allowed when you specify the workbook. Doing: `Sheet10.Range("A1:A1").Select` will work though.

Answer (score 0):

sheets("Sheet10").Range("A1").select - for single cell
sheets("Sheet10").Range("A1:B10").select - for multiple Cells